# PHPCodeSniffer rule to limit the maximum number of instructions per function / method

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I am looking for PHPCodeSniffer rule to limit the maximum number of code lines per function / method.

```
function something($b) {
    // some comment that should be ignored in the count
    $a = 12;

    $value = sqrt(
        $a * $b
    );

    return $value;
}
```

I would like the above function to be accounted as having 5 coding lines (not counting the comments an blank lines).

Answer (score 4):

I think PHPCodeSniffer (phpcs) has no standard rule for "line of code", all I can think of is to either use another metric like McCabe Cyclomatic Complexity (this is included as a Sniff called `Generic.Metrics.CyclomaticComplexity`). It's not the same, but a high value there is an indicator for messy code.

If you are willing to use another tool called [PHP Mess Detector (phpmd)](https://phpmd.org), you could use the [`ExcessiveMethodLength` rule](https://phpmd.org/rules/codesize.html#excessivemethodlength) to track the  maximum length of methods.

Comment: Thanks for trying to provide some alternative solutions!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [sniff in ObjectCalisthenics coding standard](https://github.com/object-calisthenics/phpcs-calisthenics-rules#7-keep-your-classes-small).

#### It can limit 4 metrics

- line length of class (and traits, interfaces)
- line length of method (function)
- property count in class
- method count in class